# Load website with local js/css

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

Is there a way to load someones website into webview, and then apply your css to it(that is stored in your app or some other server) ?

I have been searching for an answer for a month now, and nothing seems to work, i tried using some functions from WebView that load and store the html of the site and then load it with my url(or some similar solutions), the css is applied but then the sites javascripts dont work, the links are messed up and all sorts of problems occur.(  also jsoap is not the answer, tried it, or maybe i didnt figure it out correctly )

**Long story short, load www.some-site.com but make it use your css and remain fully functional?**

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with [WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This works but only on API11 and higher :( , sry i forgot to mention i need it fro API 7, or at least 8 ....